# Enumerator value made by or-ing other enumerators

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an enum inside a class that represents bit flags.

```
class Foo
{
    enum Bar
    {    
        BAR0 = 0x1,
        BAR1 = 0x2,
        BAR2 = 0x4,    
    };
}
```

I also have a `operator|` defined for enum `Bar` outside of class `Foo`.

```
constexpr Foo::Bar operator| (Foo::Bar lhs, Foo::Bar rhs) 
{ 
    return static_cast<Foo::Bar>(static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs)); 
}
```

I would also like to have a `constexpr` variable `BAR_ALL` that is a combination of all existing flags of `Bar` inside the class `Foo`. I tried the following but it does not compile with the error `error:  #28: expression must have a constant value`.

The full code:

```
class Foo
{
    enum Bar
    {    
        BAR0 = 0x1,
        BAR1 = 0x2,
        BAR2 = 0x4,    
    };
    friend constexpr Bar operator| (Bar lhs, Bar rhs); 
    static constexpr Bar BAR_ALL = BAR0 | BAR1 | BAR2;
};

constexpr Foo::Bar operator| (Foo::Bar lhs, Foo::Bar rhs) 
{ 
    return static_cast<Foo::Bar>(static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs)); 
}
```

I guess it makes sense that the compiler doesn't know that `BAR0 | BAR1 | BAR2` is `constexpr` since the operator is defined later in the code. My question is how would I get the desired effect of having a variable `Foo::BAR_ALL` that is `constexpr`.

Thanks for the suggestions / help in advance!

Comment: You probably meant to write `BAR1`instead of `BAR 1`.

Comment: Did you try using 
     static constexpr int BAR0 = 0x1;
and so on?

Comment: @BoPersson Yes thank you.

Comment: @choosyg I would like the variables to be enums, so they have their own type. In future I will probably make it an enum class. I am in the process of porting my project from C++03 to C++11.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that compiler doesn't know that `operator|` is not a `const_expr`, you declare it is... The bigger problem I see is that you cast `or` onto `Foo::Bar` when you can go out of the declared values. E.g. you can have `3` and there is no corresponding `Bar`. Is that even allowed?

Comment: @rozina Does the constexpr BAR_ALL have the constraint that it MUST be outside of your enum?

Comment: @luk32 Yes that is ok afaik. It works well in C++03. In my project I have all other bitwise operators defined so even though Bar variable has 3 inside, I can check which flags are set with `operator&`.

Comment: @bku_drytt I tryed having it inside the enum (that is how my code was written in C++03), however that didn't compile, since operator| is defined outside the enum and the compiler didn't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version with the functionality that you want.

```
class Foo
{
    enum Bar
    {
        BAR0 = 0x1,
        BAR1 = 0x2,
        BAR2 = 0x4,
        BAR_ALL_ = BAR0 | BAR1 | BAR2
    };
    friend constexpr Bar operator| (Bar lhs, Bar rhs);

public:
    static Bar constexpr BAR_ALL = Bar::BAR_ALL_;
};

constexpr Foo::Bar operator| (Foo::Bar lhs, Foo::Bar rhs)
{
    return static_cast<Foo::Bar>(static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs));
}

template <int I>
struct test_constexpr_bar_all {};

int main()
{
    int x{ 5 };
    // test_constexpr_bar_all<x> t1; // fails to compile because x is not a constexpr
    test_constexpr_bar_all<Foo::BAR_ALL> t1; // compiles properly
}
```

If you want to make your enum public, then you can get rid of `static Bar constexpr BAR_ALL = Bar::BAR_ALL_;` and simply access it through `Foo::Bar::BAR_ALL_`.

Here is how I would have done it:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    enum Bar
    {
        BAR0 = 0x1,
        BAR1 = 0x2,
        BAR2 = 0x4,
        BAR_ALL = BAR0 | BAR1 | BAR2
    };
private:
    friend constexpr Bar operator| (Bar lhs, Bar rhs);
};

constexpr Foo::Bar operator| (Foo::Bar lhs, Foo::Bar rhs)
{
    return static_cast<Foo::Bar>(static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs));
}

template <Foo::Bar I>
struct test_constexpr_bar_all {};

int main()
{
    test_constexpr_bar_all<Foo::Bar::BAR_ALL> t1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes in my original code the enum is public. Your code indeed compiles and that is how I have it written in C++03. It does not compile with my embedded compiler though, with the same compiler error. I guess I won't be able to keep BAR_ALL as constexpr. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are being misled by the compiler error. In fact, your code has several errors (which it seems the commenters have missed because they haven't bothered to try compiling it.)

1. `BAR 1` and `BAR 2`
2. `BAR_ALL` has no type
3. You're trying to use `operator|` before it's defined

Fixing all of these errors results in this code:

```
class Foo
{
    enum Bar
    {    
        BAR0 = 0x1,
        BAR1 = 0x2,
        BAR2 = 0x4,    
    };

    static constexpr int BAR_ALL = BAR0 | BAR1 | BAR2;
};
```

It seems from a comment you're trying to port C++03 to C++11 code. Ask yourself this: is an `enum class` *really* appropriate here? Don't shoehorn features if you don't fully understand the implications, or if the resulting maintenace costs outweighs the benefits.

Comment: @user5332965 You should explain further. If not an enum class than what? Don't leave rozina with puzzles!

Comment: Thanks for catching compiler errors. I didn't try to compile the sample code, my bad :) Your solution changes the type of BAR_ALL which is not desired. And I think I understand the use of enums and until C++11 they have been useful for bit flags. In c++11 I expect them to be even more useful as enum classes since they will be strongly typed.

Comment: @bku_drytt Care to provide the compiler version? [Here's a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b327c1bd0c62ad7) for Clang. It works for GCC too.

Comment: @kleszcz Enum classes are not meant to replace enums, just as range-based for loops are not meant to replace for loops. They are different features, use whichever is most appropriate to the application needs.

Comment: @user5332965 I must have made a mistake when copying your code. It works correctly. Sorry.

Comment: @bku_drytt I cannot comment on your post since I don't have enough rep...while your code compiles, `BAR_ALL` will *not* use the overloaded `operator|` but the built-in `operator|`.